# C# Bestpractice: Writing a method that returns a value in depdency of the method parameter that is a part of the class itself

Tags: c#

At first sorry for my really bad title! If you have a better title just change it or make a comment =)

I have this class:

```
public class Config
{
    public Provider1 Provider1 { get; set; }
    public Provider2 Provider2 { get; set; }
    public Provider3 Provider3 { get; set; }
    public Provider4 Provider4  { get; set; }
    public Provider5 Provider5 { get; set; }

    public int GetNumber(string provider)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Each provider has a Number property:

```
public interface IProvider
{
    int Number{ get; set; }
}
```

In dependency of the provider I want to return the Number of the provider.

How would you do that?

I do not want to use a big switch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public interface IProvider
{
  int Number {get;set;}
}

public class Config
{
     public int GetNumber<T>() where T : IProvider
     {
         // code to find the provider you want
         IProvider foundProvider = ProviderFactoryMethodHere(typeof(T));

         return foundProvider.Number;
     }
}
```

Now all of your provider classes need to implement the IProvider interface and you   need to implement a factory that will return the correct provider to you given the type that you've requested in the generic method.

```
// Test code example
Config configImpl = new Config();
int numberOfProvider = configImpl.GetNumber<Provider1>();
Assert.Equal(1, numberOfProvider);
```

I'll add a simple ProviderFactoryMethod example. Note that we could also make this method generic instead of passing the type as a parameter, but I'll leave the example as is.

```
public IProvider ProviderFactoryMethodHere(Type providerRequested)
{
    Dictionary <Type, IProvider> providerDict;
    if (providerDict == null)
    {
      // populate dictionary with providers, keyed by their type
      providerDict = new Dictionary<Type, IProvider>();
      providerDict.Add(typeof(Provider1), new Provider1());

      // repeat for all providers, this is pretty simple but definitely works
      // we could use other ways of holding on to your provider instances
    }
    if (providerDict.HasKey(providerRequested))
    {
        return providerDict[providerRequested];
    }
    // could throw exception here if you want to use that kind of error
    // handling, but we'll just return null for now
    return null;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: ugh, how does the factory looks like? Btw. GetNumber cannot be generic ... the provider has to be passed as a string parameter.

Comment: It looks like you're just pushing the switch statement down into the factory.

Comment: @Rookian - I've purposely removed the "string" mapping value because it is not necessary as describe so far in the requirements. It is very common for people who are not familiar with generics and using the types directly to "find" what they are looking for.  More elaborate usages of the problem code would demonstrate if we actually need the string or not.  Can you show me what the strings look like and describe why the strings are required?

Comment: @RexM - We don't need a switch statement. I've demonstrated a Dictionary now.

Comment: in the UI I have only strings as const values. I know extend the IProvider interface with a Name property. When I load the config file I put all providers in a list / List<IProvider>. Then I implemented the method GetProviderByName and GetNumber

Comment: @Rookian - It would be very easy to remove all of the generic functionality from my example and convert it to use strings.  I still have an aversion to "magic" strings used for type mapping because it diminishes our ability to refactor and get compiler type checking on the code I'm writing.  What do you use to populate the UI widget with provider values? Are they hard coded strings as well?

Comment: I do not like this strings too. But getting different implementations of an interface using a factory is (only) possible via strings ... so I used an already implemented factory for another purpose that uses this magically strings too. But at least I have refactor them into const values. But yes you are right, when refactoring comes into play it is geting very painful.

Comment: @Rookian - If the strings are a must, so be it. Removing the generic type and adding string parameters to the methods will achieve the same effect. I hope that my example mostly answered your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Add them to a dictionary keyed off the string that identifies the provider.

```
IDictionary<string, IProvider> providers = new Dictionary<string, IProvider>();
```

You can then get the values from the dictionary by checking if the dictionary contains the value passed into the GetNumber method. If it's there, you can just grab it out of the dictionary and call the Number property on the provider.

`return providers[provider].Number;`

Note that when you're defining the dictionary, IProvider needs to be the base class which all the providers inherit from.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want all of your Providers to inherit from a single base class (or interface) that provides the Number of each.

```
abstract class Provider {
   public int Number { get; set; }
}

class Provider1 : Provider { ... }
```

Then you can dump all of your Providers in a hash table keyed by whatever that string is you're using.  For example:

```
public class Config
{
   Dictionary<string, Provider> _providers = new Dictionary<string, Provider>();

   // .. all of your providers ..

   public int GetNumber(string provider)
   {
      if (!_providers.HasKey(provider))
         throw ArgumentException();
      return _providers[provider].Number;
   }
}
```

Comment: Putting aside the use of a common base instead of a common interface, why would we want to special case the `Number` property instead of just returning any provider based on its name?

Comment: Because that's what the OP asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Is the provider's number a property of a base class or interface that all providers implement, or is it a property of its position in the config class?

*edit*

If it's a property of the provider, then the right way to access it is through the provider.  In other words, `Config` should return some child of `IProvider` (or whatever you call it), and the caller can then chain to its `Number` property.

*edit*

Part of the problem is that you have enumerated property names ("prop1", "prop2", etc).  Why not replace this with an indexer or a method that takes an index?

Another issue is that you seem to want to look up the `Number` by provider name, but there's no place shown where a name exists.  Do you mean the class name?

Comment: it is a property of the provider that is inheriting an interface

Comment: that is not an answer, make that a comment to his question instead.

Comment: @Blub: better yet, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: What's funny is that I picked the same property and interface names independently.

Comment: @Rookian: Ok, but there's some arbitrary number of them.  So, rather than each getting its own property, let them share an indexer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface.

IGiveANumberbackable
{
  GetNumber();
}

Implement this in your classes.

Call this method on your class instead of GetNumber()

Comment: So instead of calling `IProvider.GetNumber`, you want to call `IGiveANumberbackable.GetNumber` ? Or am I missing something?